# will a generated REST client proxy fail if the service is updated with additional fields in response?

Tags: rest, proxy, webservice-client, backwards-compatibility

We have an RPC-soap service. If we add new optional fields to the response data from the service, this can potentially break client applications, depending on the SOAP toolkit the client uses, if the client proxy is not updated to sync with the latest service API.

Could the same situation occur between client applications and a REST service, where the client applications use a REST client proxy generator on the WADL or WSDL2.0? Or do these REST clients gracefully handle data in the response that is unexpected, by ignoring those fields? Does it depend on the REST client toolkit?